# Add edge-weights to plot output in networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am doing some graph theory in python using the networkx package. I would like 
to add the weights of the edges of my graph to the plot output. How can I do this?

For example How would I modify the following code to get the desired output?

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.Graph()
i=1
G.add_node(i,pos=(i,i))
G.add_node(2,pos=(2,2))
G.add_node(3,pos=(1,0))
G.add_edge(1,2,weight=0.5)
G.add_edge(1,3,weight=9.8)
pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')
nx.draw(G,pos)
plt.savefig("path.png")
```

I would like 0.5 and 9.8 to appear on the edges to which they refer in the graph.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You'll have to call [`nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edge_labels.html), which will allow you to... draw networkX edge labels :)

EDIT: full modified source

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.Graph()
i=1
G.add_node(i,pos=(i,i))
G.add_node(2,pos=(2,2))
G.add_node(3,pos=(1,0))
G.add_edge(1,2,weight=0.5)
G.add_edge(1,3,weight=9.8)
pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')
nx.draw(G,pos)
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels)
plt.savefig(<wherever>)
```

Comment: @Joel: added full source; I wasn't only linking to docs, I was actually proposing a method :)

Comment: @Joel: Oh, I didn't know that one :)

Comment: I went ahead and put that edit in.  I think the code is about as clean as it gets now.  Not sure why I had an error earlier (in fact the code I thought I was giving me an error now runs cleanly...).

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: I'm surprised (but happy) this answer is getting this much attention! If one of the people coming along here could comment what they were trying to do when they encountered the question that this answers, I'd be thankful!

Comment: This shows: {weight: xxxxx} in the edge. Anyway we can get just the number in the edge label?

Comment: yes. Replace `labels`  with the number you mean. seriously, this is Python – can't be that hard to fix that line of code :)

Comment: It seems that `nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels()` can't show distance given `labels`, edges with larger weights shown in the plot should look longer than those with smaller weights.

Comment: Please ask a new question instead of raising questions in the comments. Thank you!

Comment: The link in the  answer to the docs gives Error 404: Page not found so here is the new link: 

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edge_labels.html

Comment: @MarcusMüller, to answer your question about why I came to this answer, I'm trying to understand how to configure [pymaxflow](https://github.com/pmneila/PyMaxflow), and was looking for a way to visualize the weights it assigns to each edge. This answer gave me what I needed!

Comment: @ForeverWintr oh, interesting! Yes, that is indeed something I'm very happy to learn! This library goes into my toolbox.

Comment: what if you have no pos specified?

Comment: Then you don't have an embedded graph that you could draw. @mathtick I think you might be trying to ask a separate, larger question. Please don't do that in the comments!

Answer (score 43):

I like to do it like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pos=nx.spring_layout(G) # pos = nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G,pos)
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels)
```