# Is there a way to draw the network diagram using correlation coefficient as the basis of connections?

Tags: python, algorithm, networking, pearson-correlation

I wish to draw network diagram based on the correlations between columns for eg.
My data which has 200 rows & 100 columns,sample as below:

| A (Zone1) | B(Zone1) | C (Zone2) | D (Zone2) | E (Zone3) | F (Zone3) | G (FInal) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 23 | 21 | 4 | 4 | 34 | 33 |
| 4 | -2 | 7 | 3 | 10 | 4 | 12 |
| 23 | 21 | 4 | 4 | 34 | 33 | 12 |
| 10 | 4 | 12 | 0 | 4 | -2 | 7 |

So the network I want to see is zone wise column names according to their correlation value:

[image]

So if there are no good correlation (<=0.3) between 2 columns those should not connected using correlation.
Is there an algorithm or way to do this in python?

Comment: I would use [`.corr` to get the pairwise correlations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.corr.html), [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to read the data from the csv file, and [`networkx` to build the graph](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following tools:

- [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to read the data from the csv file;
- [`.corr` to get the pairwise correlations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.corr.html);
- [`networkx` to build the graph](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html).

```py
import pandas
import itertools
import networkx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')

vertices = data.columns.values.tolist()
edges = [((u,v),data[u].corr(data[v])) for u,v in itertools.combinations(vertices, 2)]
edges = [(u,v,{'weight': c}) for (u,v),c in edges if c >= 0.3]

G = networkx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)

networkx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')
plt.show()
```

[image: Graph with edges if correlation >= 0.3]

See also this question:

- [Add edge weights to plot output in networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372127/add-edge-weights-to-plot-output-in-networkx)