# How do you make weight appear on matrix by using nx.to_numpy_matrix?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, edges, sna

I am making SNA network graph using networkx librabry from python. I used a lesmis.gml data(lesmiserable data) and the data is like this

`graph [ node [ id 0 label "Myriel" ] node [ id 1 label "Napoleon" ] node [ id 2 label "MlleBaptistine" ] node [ id 3 label "MmeMagloire" ] node [ id 4 label "CountessDeLo" ] node [ id 5 label "Geborand" ] node [ id 6 label "Champtercier" ] node [ id 7 label "Cravatte" ] node [ id 8 label "Count" ] node [ id 9 label "OldMan" ] node [ id 10 label "Labarre" ] node [ id 11 label "Valjean" ] node [ id 12 label "Marguerite" ] node [ id 13 label "MmeDeR" ] node [ id 14 label "Isabeau" ] node [ id 15 label "Gervais" ] node [ id 16 label "Tholomyes" ] node [ id 17 label "Listolier" ] node [ id 18 label "Fameuil" ] node [ id 19 label "Blacheville" ] node [ id 20 label "Favourite" ] node [ id 21 label "Dahlia" ] node [ id 22 label "Zephine" ] node [ id 23 label "Fantine" ] node [ id 24 label "MmeThenardier" ] node [ id 25 label "Thenardier" ] node [ id 26 label "Cosette" ] node [ id 27 label "Javert" ] node [ id 28 label "Fauchelevent" ] node [ id 29 label "Bamatabois" ] node [ id 30 label "Perpetue" ] node [ id 31 label "Simplice" ] node [ id 32 label "Scaufflaire" ] node [ id 33 label "Woman1" ] node [ id 34 label "Judge" ] node [ id 35 label "Champmathieu" ] node [ id 36 label "Brevet" ] node [ id 37 label "Chenildieu" ] node [ id 38 label "Cochepaille" ] node [ id 39 label "Pontmercy" ] node [ id 40 label "Boulatruelle" ] node [ id 41 label "Eponine" ] node [ id 42 label "Anzelma" ] node [ id 43 label "Woman2" ] node [ id 44 label "MotherInnocent" ] node [ id 45 label "Gribier" ] node [ id 46 label "Jondrette" ] node [ id 47 label "MmeBurgon" ] node [ id 48 label "Gavroche" ] node [ id 49 label "Gillenormand" ] node [ id 50 label "Magnon" ] node [ id 51 label "MlleGillenormand" ] node [ id 52 label "MmePontmercy" ] node [ id 53 label "MlleVaubois" ] node [ id 54 label "LtGillenormand" ] node [ id 55 label "Marius" ] node [ id 56 label "BaronessT" ] node [ id 57 label "Mabeuf" ] node [ id 58 label "Enjolras" ] node [ id 59 label "Combeferre" ] node [ id 60 label "Prouvaire" ] node [ id 61 label "Feuilly" ] node [ id 62 label "Courfeyrac" ] node [ id 63 label "Bahorel" ] node [ id 64 label "Bossuet" ] node [ id 65 label "Joly" ] node [ id 66 label "Grantaire" ] node [ id 67 label "MotherPlutarch" ] node [ id 68 label "Gueulemer" ] node [ id 69 label "Babet" ] node [ id 70 label "Claquesous" ] node [ id 71 label "Montparnasse" ] node [ id 72 label "Toussaint" ] node [ id 73 label "Child1" ] node [ id 74 label "Child2" ] node [ id 75 label "Brujon" ] node [ id 76 label "MmeHucheloup" ] edge [ source 1 target 0 value 1 ] edge [ source 2 target 0 value 8 ] edge [ source 3 target 0 value 10 ] edge [ source 3 target 2 value 6 ] edge [ source 4 target 0 value 1 ] edge [ source 5 target 0 value 1 ] edge [ source 6 target 0 value 1 ] edge [ source 7 target 0 value 1 ] edge [ source 8 target 0 value 2 ] edge [ source 9 target 0 value 1 ] edge [ source 11 target 10 value 1 ] edge [ source 11 target 3 value 3 ] edge [ source 11 target 2 value 3 ] edge [ source 11 target 0 value 5 ] edge [ source 12 target 11 value 1 ] edge [ source 13 target 11 value 1 ] edge [ source 14 target 11 value 1 ] edge [ source 15 target 11 value 1 ] edge [ source 17 target 16 value 4 ] edge [ source 18 target 16 value 4 ] edge [ source 18 target 17 value 4 ] edge [ source 19 target 16 value 4 ] edge [ source 19 target 17 value 4 ] edge [ source 19 target 18 value 4 ] edge [ source 20 target 16 value 3 ] edge [ source 20 target 17 value 3 ] edge [ source 20 target 18 value 3 ] edge [ source 20 target 19 value 4 ] edge [ source 21 target 16 value 3 ] edge [ source 21 target 17 value 3 ] edge [ source 21 target 18 value 3 ] edge [ source 21 target 19 value 3 ] edge [ source 21 target 20 value 5 ] edge [ source 22 target 16 value 3 ] edge [ source 22 target 17 value 3 ] edge [ source 22 target 18 value 3 ] edge [ source 22 target 19 value 3 ] edge [ source 22 target 20 value 4 ] edge [ source 22 target 21 value 4 ] edge [ source 23 target 16 value 3 ] edge [ source 23 target 17 value 3 ] edge [ source 23 target 18 value 3 ] edge [ source 23 target 19 value 3 ] edge [ source 23 target 20 value 4 ] edge [ source 23 target 21 value 4 ] edge [ source 23 target 22 value 4 ] edge [ source 23 target 12 value 2 ] edge [ source 23 target 11 value 9 ] edge [ source 24 target 23 value 2 ] edge [ source 24 target 11 value 7 ] edge [ source 25 target 24 value 13 ] edge [ source 25 target 23 value 1 ] edge [ source 25 target 11 value 12 ] edge [ source 26 target 24 value 4 ] edge [ source 26 target 11 value 31 ] edge [ source 26 target 16 value 1 ] edge [ source 26 target 25 value 1 ] edge [ source 27 target 11 value 17 ] edge [ source 27 target 23 value 5 ] edge [ source 27 target 25 value 5 ] edge [ source 27 target 24 value 1 ] edge [ source 27 target 26 value 1 ] edge [ source 28 target 11 value 8 ] edge [ source 28 target 27 value 1 ] edge [ source 29 target 23 value 1 ] edge [ source 29 target 27 value 1 ] edge [ source 29 target 11 value 2 ] edge [ source 30 target 23 value 1 ] edge [ source 31 target 30 value 2 ] edge [ source 31 target 11 value 3 ] edge [ source 31 target 23 value 2 ] edge [ source 31 target 27 value 1 ] edge [ source 32 target 11 value 1 ] edge [ source 33 target 11 value 2 ] edge [ source 33 target 27 value 1 ] edge [ source 34 target 11 value 3 ] edge [ source 34 target 29 value 2 ] edge [ source 35 target 11 value 3 ] edge [ source 35 target 34 value 3 ] edge [ source 35 target 29 value 2 ] edge [ source 36 target 34 value 2 ] edge [ source 36 target 35 value 2 ] edge [ source 36 target 11 value 2 ] edge [ source 36 target 29 value 1 ] edge [ source 37 target 34 value 2 ] edge [ source 37 target 35 value 2 ] edge [ source 37 target 36 value 2 ] edge [ source 37 target 11 value 2 ] edge [ source 37 target 29 value 1 ] edge [ source 38 target 34 value 2 ] edge [ source 38 target 35 value 2 ] edge [ source 38 target 36 value 2 ] edge [ source 38 target 37 value 2 ] edge [ source 38 target 11 value 2 ] edge [ source 38 target 29 value 1 ] edge [ source 39 target 25 value 1 ] edge [ source 40 target 25 value 1 ] edge [ source 41 target 24 value 2 ] edge [ source 41 target 25 value 3 ] edge [ source 42 target 41 value 2 ] edge [ source 42 target 25 value 2 ] edge [ source 42 target 24 value 1 ] edge [ source 43 target 11 value 3 ] edge [ source 43 target 26 value 1 ] edge [ source 43 target 27 value 1 ] edge [ source 44 target 28 value 3 ] edge [ source 44 target 11 value 1 ] edge [ source 45 target 28 value 2 ] edge [ source 47 target 46 value 1 ] edge [ source 48 target 47 value 2 ] edge [ source 48 target 25 value 1 ] edge [ source 48 target 27 value 1 ] edge [ source 48 target 11 value 1 ] edge [ source 49 target 26 value 3 ] edge [ source 49 target 11 value 2 ] edge [ source 50 target 49 value 1 ] edge [ source 50 target 24 value 1 ] edge [ source 51 target 49 value 9 ] edge [ source 51 target 26 value 2 ] edge [ source 51 target 11 value 2 ] edge [ source 52 target 51 value 1 ] edge [ source 52 target 39 value 1 ] edge [ source 53 target 51 value 1 ] edge [ source 54 target 51 value 2 ] edge [ source 54 target 49 value 1 ] edge [ source 54 target 26 value 1 ] edge [ source 55 target 51 value 6 ] edge [ source 55 target 49 value 12 ] edge [ source 55 target 39 value 1 ] edge [ source 55 target 54 value 1 ] edge [ source 55 target 26 value 21 ] edge [ source 55 target 11 value 19 ] edge [ source 55 target 16 value 1 ] edge [ source 55 target 25 value 2 ] edge [ source 55 target 41 value 5 ] edge [ source 55 target 48 value 4 ] edge [ source 56 target 49 value 1 ] edge [ source 56 target 55 value 1 ] edge [ source 57 target 55 value 1 ] edge [ source 57 target 41 value 1 ] edge [ source 57 target 48 value 1 ] edge [ source 58 target 55 value 7 ] edge [ source 58 target 48 value 7 ] edge [ source 58 target 27 value 6 ] edge [ source 58 target 57 value 1 ] edge [ source 58 target 11 value 4 ] edge [ source 59 target 58 value 15 ] edge [ source 59 target 55 value 5 ] edge [ source 59 target 48 value 6 ] edge [ source 59 target 57 value 2 ] edge [ source 60 target 48 value 1 ] edge [ source 60 target 58 value 4 ] edge [ source 60 target 59 value 2 ] edge [ source 61 target 48 value 2 ] edge [ source 61 target 58 value 6 ] edge [ source 61 target 60 value 2 ] edge [ source 61 target 59 value 5 ] edge [ source 61 target 57 value 1 ] edge [ source 61 target 55 value 1 ] edge [ source 62 target 55 value 9 ] edge [ source 62 target 58 value 17 ] edge [ source 62 target 59 value 13 ] edge [ source 62 target 48 value 7 ] edge [ source 62 target 57 value 2 ] edge [ source 62 target 41 value 1 ] edge [ source 62 target 61 value 6 ] edge [ source 62 target 60 value 3 ] edge [ source 63 target 59 value 5 ] edge [ source 63 target 48 value 5 ] edge [ source 63 target 62 value 6 ] edge [ source 63 target 57 value 2 ] edge [ source 63 target 58 value 4 ] edge [ source 63 target 61 value 3 ] edge [ source 63 target 60 value 2 ] edge [ source 63 target 55 value 1 ] edge [ source 64 target 55 value 5 ] edge [ source 64 target 62 value 12 ] edge [ source 64 target 48 value 5 ] edge [ source 64 target 63 value 4 ] edge [ source 64 target 58 value 10 ] edge [ source 64 target 61 value 6 ] edge [ source 64 target 60 value 2 ] edge [ source 64 target 59 value 9 ] edge [ source 64 target 57 value 1 ] edge [ source 64 target 11 value 1 ] edge [ source 65 target 63 value 5 ] edge [ source 65 target 64 value 7 ] edge [ source 65 target 48 value 3 ] edge [ source 65 target 62 value 5 ] edge [ source 65 target 58 value 5 ] edge [ source 65 target 61 value 5 ] edge [ source 65 target 60 value 2 ] edge [ source 65 target 59 value 5 ] edge [ source 65 target 57 value 1 ] edge [ source 65 target 55 value 2 ] edge [ source 66 target 64 value 3 ] edge [ source 66 target 58 value 3 ] edge [ source 66 target 59 value 1 ] edge [ source 66 target 62 value 2 ] edge [ source 66 target 65 value 2 ] edge [ source 66 target 48 value 1 ] edge [ source 66 target 63 value 1 ] edge [ source 66 target 61 value 1 ] edge [ source 66 target 60 value 1 ] edge [ source 67 target 57 value 3 ] edge [ source 68 target 25 value 5 ] edge [ source 68 target 11 value 1 ] edge [ source 68 target 24 value 1 ] edge [ source 68 target 27 value 1 ] edge [ source 68 target 48 value 1 ] edge [ source 68 target 41 value 1 ] edge [ source 69 target 25 value 6 ] edge [ source 69 target 68 value 6 ] edge [ source 69 target 11 value 1 ] edge [ source 69 target 24 value 1 ] edge [ source 69 target 27 value 2 ] edge [ source 69 target 48 value 1 ] edge [ source 69 target 41 value 1 ] edge [ source 70 target 25 value 4 ] edge [ source 70 target 69 value 4 ] edge [ source 70 target 68 value 4 ] edge [ source 70 target 11 value 1 ] edge [ source 70 target 24 value 1 ] edge [ source 70 target 27 value 1 ] edge [ source 70 target 41 value 1 ] edge [ source 70 target 58 value 1 ] edge [ source 71 target 27 value 1 ] edge [ source 71 target 69 value 2 ] edge [ source 71 target 68 value 2 ] edge [ source 71 target 70 value 2 ] edge [ source 71 target 11 value 1 ] edge [ source 71 target 48 value 1 ] edge [ source 71 target 41 value 1 ] edge [ source 71 target 25 value 1 ] edge [ source 72 target 26 value 2 ] edge [ source 72 target 27 value 1 ] edge [ source 72 target 11 value 1 ] edge [ source 73 target 48 value 2 ] edge [ source 74 target 48 value 2 ] edge [ source 74 target 73 value 3 ] edge [ source 75 target 69 value 3 ] edge [ source 75 target 68 value 3 ] edge [ source 75 target 25 value 3 ] edge [ source 75 target 48 value 1 ] edge [ source 75 target 41 value 1 ] edge [ source 75 target 70 value 1 ] edge [ source 75 target 71 value 1 ] edge [ source 76 target 64 value 1 ] edge [ source 76 target 65 value 1 ] edge [ source 76 target 66 value 1 ] edge [ source 76 target 63 value 1 ] edge [ source 76 target 62 value 1 ] edge [ source 76 target 48 value 1 ] edge [ source 76 target 58 value 1 ] ]`

Here's my code to draw network graph.

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import zipfile
from google.colab import files



myfile = files.upload()
G = nx.read_gml('lesmis.gml')
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos,with_labels=True,node_color = 'yellow', node_size = 200, edge_color = 'green',arrowsize = 1000, width = 1 )
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'value')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=labels)
```

I want to make matrix by using nx.to_numpy_matrix(G) but this only shows binary figure(1,0). I want the figure in matrix to be a 'value'(=weight) from dataset. How do you do this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add edge-weights to plot output in networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372127/add-edge-weights-to-plot-output-in-networkx)

Comment: Oops I posted wrong question..  
I changed my question.

Comment: might help to follow this guide for posting questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example